# Google Spreadsheet Java API - Protect Worksheet

Tags: java, gdata, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to programmatically protect a worksheet in a spreadsheet to only allow specific people to edit it?

I can't find any decent documentation or examples on how to do this. The only things I can find that may be relevant are the `setRights()`/`getRights()` and `getContributors()` methods in [BaseEntry.java](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/BaseEntry), which I don't think are any good, but I don't know because there's no documentation.

Is there are feed URL I can post to to update the list of contributors?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

### Google-apps-script

Looks to be possible with Google-apps-script

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setSheetProtection(PageProtection)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setSheetProtection%28PageProtection%29)

### Gdata - spreadsheet api

there is nothing close to that in the spreadsheet api. Even basics 
like set cell color or insert row don't exist. (there an append row)

It works fine for data and calculation but little else.

Comment: Thanks for that, but there doesn't seem to be any way to work with Apps Script through a Java application...or maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: You can send parameters via a GET to a Google-apps-script (server side java script) program. The sending bit is clean and uncomplicated. There are ways to get a result back, that I have seen posted, but these look a little messy. I have never tried to get results back.